# Push img resolution from loop to array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I receive an array of images and want to get the resolution (width, height) and store them properly to the db. How can I push the resolution `const resolution` correctly into the array of the respective file?

```js
const FilesStorage = require("../models/filesStorageModel");
const sizeOf = require('image-size');
const url = require('url')
const https = require('https')

exports.uploadFiles = async (req, res) => {
    const filesArray = req.files

    try {
        for (const file of filesArray) {

            const imgUrl = file.location
            const options = url.parse(imgUrl)

            https.get(options, (res) => {
                const chunks = []
                res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    chunks.push(chunk)
                }).on('end', () => {
                    const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks)
                    const resolution = sizeOf(buffer)

                    console.log(resolution)
                })
            })


            const uploadFiles = new FilesStorage({
                name: file.originalname,
                altTag: "alt",
                format: file.mimetype,
                filePath: file.location,
                sizeKB: (file.size / 1000),
                
                height: "resolution.height", // How?
                width: "resolution.width", // How?
            })
    
            await uploadFiles.save()
        }
    
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Files successfully uploaded',
        })

    } catch(err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: `Something wen't wrong`,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to add resolution as a property of the File Object in your filesArray?

Comment: Exactly @Kwright02

Comment: What do you plan to do with it exactly? It won't append anything to the actual files

Comment: Of course, it does not work currently. That is why I am here. :-)
I want to be able to retrieve and display `height` and `width` later in the frontend.

Comment: Are you just forwarding this information to the front end with the API request? Or will it need to be retrieved much later?

Comment: Here I just want to store the files and its information in the database (MongoDB). Later I want to be able to retrieve the files and their information in the frontend and edit e.g. the name. This is all no problem for me. I just have difficulties to add the resolution from the loop to each respective file.

Comment: I see, one moment for the soloution

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer you're looking for:

First, we need to consider variable scopes. When we look at the resolution constant you have defined in your handler, we can see the scope makes it local to that handler and not the parent code block.

To make it accessible in other areas of the code block, we move it above the handler scope but keep it inside your for loop so it's file-specific. With this change, we can now insert the resolution into your database upload call.

Hope this helps!

```js
const FilesStorage = require("../models/filesStorageModel");
const sizeOf = require('image-size');
const url = require('url')
const https = require('https')

exports.uploadFiles = async(req, res) => {
  const filesArray = req.files

  try {
    for (const file of filesArray) {

      const imgUrl = file.location
      const options = url.parse(imgUrl)
      
      //Added variable outside arrow function scope
      var resolution;

      https.get(options, (res) => {
        const chunks = []
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          chunks.push(chunk)
        }).on('end', () => {
        
          const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks)
          
          //Set value to variable outside function scope
          resolution = sizeOf(buffer)
          
          console.log(resolution)
        })
      })


      const uploadFiles = new FilesStorage({
        name: file.originalname,
        altTag: "alt",
        format: file.mimetype,
        filePath: file.location,
        sizeKB: (file.size / 1000),

        //Get value by accessing variable above
        height: resolution.height,
        width: resolution.width,
      })

      await uploadFiles.save()
    }

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Files successfully uploaded',
    })

  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: `Something wen't wrong`,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It triggers the error `Cannot read property 'height' of undefined`