# Fileupload - Get image resolution

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to get the resolution (height, width) of the images I am sending to the backend. Attention, in this example several images are sent to the backend at once. So, we are working with loops!

I tried to find a solution in the backend, but couldn't find anything. Here is the corresponding stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73112916/push-img-resolution-from-loop-to-array) I asked.

Now I am asking for a way to do this in the frontend. When I `console.log(file)` following example will be outputed:

```json
lastModified: 1657671728196
lastModifiedDate: Wed Jul 13 2022 02:22:08 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit) {}
name: "Example.png"
size: 3128
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Too bad that the resolution is not callable this way. Furthermore I would like to save the img-type in the db but not as `image/png` but as `png` or `jpeg` etc. only.

```js
async submitFiles() {
      const formData = new FormData()

      for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        const file = this.files[i]
        formData.append('files', file)

        console.log(file)
      }

      try {
        const response = await this.$axios.post('/api/upload-files', formData, {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
          onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            this.uploadPercentage = parseInt(
              Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100)
            )
          },
        })

        const result = response.data

        if (result.success) {
          if (this.uploadPercentage === 100) {
            this.$nuxt.refresh()
            this.$emit('exit', true)
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
```

Comment: The fact that it's a loop is not an issue per se, if it works for one it will work for every one of them. As for `image/png`, it's a MIME type so this is basically a regular PNG that you may want, just more precise and used by your OS to tell it which program to use when clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

Checking for resolution in the browser is pretty straightforward. All you need to do is create an Image element out of the user provided file.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      files: [],
      formData: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    formData() {
      if (this.formData.getAll('files').length === this.files.length) {
        this.submitFiles()
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.formData = new FormData()
  },
  methods: {
    async submitFiles() {
      try {
        const data = this.formData
        const response = await this.$axios.post(
          '/api/upload-files', data,
          {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
            onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
              this.uploadPercentage = parseInt(
                Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100)
              )
            },
          }
        )

        const result = response.data

        if (result.success) {
          if (this.uploadPercentage === 100) {
            this.$nuxt.refresh()
            this.$emit('exit', true)
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
    processFiles() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        const file = this.files[i]

        const img = new Image()
        const vm = this
        img.onload = function () {
          file.width = this.width
          file.height = this.height
          console.log(file)
          vm.formData.append('files', file)
        }
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
      }
    },
  },
}
```

As for the mime type of the image you could split the string by `/` and save the right half:

```js
const [,type] = file.type.split('/')
```

EDIT:
The callbacks will not be called when you try to post your data (inside the `try` block), so it would be a good idea to watch the `formData` until it's length matches the length of the `files` array. Then we know all of the images are processed and it's safe to send data to our backend.

Comment: Thank you, through the function I can get the resolution. Now how can I push this new data into the file array into the respective file? So that I can save them in the db.

Comment: Edited the answer so that the resolution is saved inside the `files`

Comment: Looks awesome! Unfortunately in the data() return 'section' I get the error: `FormData is not defined`

Comment: Found a solution. One moment please!

Comment: I have posted an answer. It works, hopefully correctly. If you think it works properly, you can edit your answer with my changes so that your answer is 100% correct and I can accept it. Thank you so much! You're my hero!

Comment: Oops, height and width are not arriving in the backend. I will keep trying, my bad. But they are displayed in the console.log in the frontend

Comment: See, the problem with your code is that you append the file to formData without waiting for the onload function to execute. This way the data is sent before the width and height are set. You must append inside `onload`. I've edited my answer to include the full code.

Note that it's important that you call `processFiles` when your user clicks "send" (or whatever triggers form submition). `submitFiles` will be called by the watcher.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's what I discovered and understood just now too. But unfortunately I still can't place `formData: new FormData()` in the data return section. It immediately fires `FormData is not defined`.

Comment: Oh right, you're on nuxt. Fair enough :)

Comment: I'm so sorry! `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'append') at img.onload`

Comment: You're right! We're dealing with the context of `onload`, so we have to save Vues `this` somewhere else. Fixed

Comment: It's really so sad! It looks like it won't work with `this` in nuxt. I only receive an empty array in the backend now. I have already taken up so much of your time. But do you think I should look for a solution in the backend again?

Maybe I'll ask a new question with all the new information we've received at this point. Unfortunately, I don't have much time today.