# How to send images with their resolution via multipart/form-data to backend? (NuxtJS)

Tags: nuxt.js, multipartform-data, form-data

Perhaps this question is a bit confusing. I have built a fileuploader wherein I want to send images to the backend. All no problem, however I want to send the **resolution** of the images **(height, width)** also to the backend and store it in the database.

User [akopyl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8124983/akopyl) helped me a lot yesterday, unfortunately we didn't come up with a working result for **NuxtJS**. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73127963/fileupload-get-image-resolution) the related question. Have a look to the comments of his answer.

**The problem**

Inside `img.onload` in `processFiles()` we need to append the newly received information (height, width) to the FormData. Inside `img.onload` it doesn't work though, I just receive an empty array in the backend.

We try to get the resolution of the images and add them to formData.append('files', file).

I search everywhere on the internet and wonder why I can't find a solution. It can not be that no one but me is looking for the question: **How can I send images with their resolution via multipart/form-data?**

```js
  data() {
    return {
      files: [],
      formData: null,
    }
  },

  watch: {
    formData() {
      if (this.formData.getAll('files').length === this.files.length) {
        this.submitFiles()
      }
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.formData = new FormData()

    this.$refs.fileform.addEventListener(
      'drop',
      function (e) {
        for (let i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
          this.files.push(e.dataTransfer.files[i])
        }
        this.submitFiles()
        this.processFiles()
      }.bind(this)
    )
  },

  methods: {
    processFiles() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        const file = this.files[i]

        const img = new Image()
        const vm = this
        img.onload = function () {
          file.width = this.width
          file.height = this.height
          console.log(file)
          vm.formData.append('files', file)
        }
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
      }
    },

    async submitFiles() {
      try {
        const data = this.formData
        const response = await this.$axios.post('/api/upload-files', data, {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
          onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            this.uploadPercentage = parseInt(
              Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100)
            )
          },
        })

        const result = response.data

        if (result.success) {
          if (this.uploadPercentage === 100) {
            this.$nuxt.refresh()
            this.$emit('exit', true)
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: submitFiles is async and your calling processFiles after, combine both them methods into one

Comment: That was the starting point yesterday, so this doesn't solve the problem.